# Simulate key strokes in HTML textbox in geckoWebBrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyevent, gecko

I am using the "geckoWebBrowser1" component. I have navigated to an URL that will show an login textbox with ID: login-email

Now I do successfully put "someemail@hotmail.com" into that textbox.
However, it is nessecary to actually type the email where the the textbox detects keydown/keyup etc events. So when I try to click on the login button, it beleives that no text exist in the textbox afterall even that the "someemail@hotmail.com" is there.

So I wonder how can I safely simulate key events when I write the email there. It has to be safe so "SendKeys.Send" should not be used if the window is not active. I am looking for a safe way to do this. For example is it possible to inject javascript for this?

The HTML for the textbox looks like this:

```js
<input type="email" autocomplete="username" name="email" id="login-email" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter e-mail" class="el-input__inner">
```

//The code I use

```js
        private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Input email address into this textBox when the "geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted" fires!

            //<input type="email" autocomplete="username" name="email" id="login-email" 
            //autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter e-mail" class="el-input__inner">
            foreach (var elements in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
            {
                if (elements.Id.ToLower() == "login-email")
                {
                    elements.SetAttribute("value", "someemail@hotmail.com");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. The below solution simulates the keypress event and put each letter one by one into the textbox.

Thank you!

```js
        private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Input email address
            //<input type="email" autocomplete="username" name="email" id="login-email" 
            //autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter e-mail" class="el-input__inner">
            foreach (var elements in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
            {
                if (elements.Id.ToLower() == "login-email")
                {
                    String username = "someemail@hotmail.com";
                    DomEventArgs ev = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.CreateEvent("KeyEvents");
                    var webEvent = new Gecko.WebIDL.Event(geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, ev.DomEvent as nsISupports);
                    webEvent.InitEvent("focus", true, false);
                    elements.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);
                    var nsIEventVar = ((nsIDOMKeyEvent)ev.DomEvent);
                    char[] inputChars = username.ToCharArray();
                    foreach (var vchar in inputChars)
                    {
                        int keyCode = (int)(System.Windows.Forms.Keys)vchar;
                        nsIEventVar.InitKeyEvent(new nsAString("keypress"), true, false, geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, false, false, false, false, (uint)keyCode, (uint)keyCode);
                        Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMEventTarget>(elements.DomObject).DispatchEvent(nsIEventVar);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```